# creating a permanent folder in /tmp/ of ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, temporary-directory, permanent

**how to create a permanent folder in the temporary folder in ubuntu?** without being deleted when the computer shuts down, and not have to repeat the process every time the computer restarts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, `/tmp/` gets cleaned on reboot.  You may need to place stateful information into `/var/run/$myapp/` or a similar spot.  Make sure you clean that once it grows.